# apache 000-default virtual host

Tags: apache2

I see that there's the 000-default virtual host and I left it.  I created a new file and link for mysite.com and it works, but not how I want it to.  I'm wondering, does anyone know if I need to delete or if I shouldn't delete the 000-default vh?

For some reason if to go to http://mysite.com it takes me to the 000-default site, but if I go to http://www.mysite.com it takes me to the correct place.  Why is there a difference?

This is mysite.com vh file:

```
#NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin nick@mysite.com
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com *.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /home/nick/www/mysite.com

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.com/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel info

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.com/access.log common
        ServerSignature On

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Well, I deleted the 000-default link completely....and still the exact same behavior.  I did notice this, if I do to mysite.com it takes me to that apache default "It works!" page, but if I go to mysite.com/index.html it takes me to my own correct index.html file.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it looks like:
mysite.com/index.html == www.mysite.com but is different than mysite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configured like that, there is no need for default VH. 
Now, why mysite.com takes you to default? That's a good question, if your configuration is exactly as you've copied, you have restarted the server, then it shouldn't.

Comment: Well, possibly because of the default-000 file which I haven't shown?  It is perfectly safe to delete the 000-default then?

Comment: ok, here how I got it to work...
After deleting the 000-default link, I then had to uncomment #NameVirtualHost

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using "*_default_*" virtual host may solve the problem: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default

It is good practise to change default virtual host configuration to "*_default_*" after creating another virtual host configuration.

Comment: Makes me wonder why "_default_" isn't standard in the 000-default virtual host?